# Toggle up and down arrows in a simple accordion widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have followed few tutorials and then created a simple accordion widget, it works fine as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gu7h3/2)

However, I am trying to add a downward arrow when the section is closed and an upper arrow when the section is open - at the right end of the head of each tab in the accordion, just as the image below shows:

[image]
Here is the arrows font codes:

```
.icon-arrowUp:before {
   content: "\f077";
}
.icon-arrowDown:before {
   content: "\f078";
}
```

Here is what I have tried, I added the downward arrow by default using CSS:

```
.accordian .accordian-head:before {
        font-family: 'icons';
        content: "\f078";
        float: right;
    }
```

This added the arrow nicely, however now I want it to replace that arrow with the upward one when the section is open, I have no clue what to do! I tried to add the following CSS and toggle it with JavaScript, but it didn't work:

```
.accordian .accordian-head .accordian-head-active:before {
        font-family: 'icons';
        content: "\f077";
        background-color: red;
    }


//Accordian
    $('.accordion').each(function () {
        var $accordian = $(this);
        $accordian.find('.accordion-head').on('click', function () {
            $accordian.find('.accordion-body').slideUp();
            if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                $(this).next().slideDown();
                $(this).addClass('accordian-head-active');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cXEZx/) is something for you to play with

Comment: @BatuZet this worked! but how can I replace it with my arrows? I can't do it... I tried adding the codes but it just won't do it. Please advice

Comment: If you look at `.accordion .accordion-head span` style youre gonna see the `background-image` i've used for. Check it and change it accordingly to whatever u like.

Comment: I just tried: http://jsfiddle.net/x5hPR/

Comment: I tried something like: $accordian.find('.accordian-head').css(":before",'\f078')

Answer (score 5):

I have using CSS border - Arrow

**JS**

```
$('.accordion').each(function () {
        var $accordian = $(this);
        $accordian.find('.accordion-head').on('click', function () {
            $accordian.find('.accordion-body').slideUp();
            if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                $(this).next().slideDown();
                   $('h4 span',this).text("Up Arrow");
            }else{
                $('h4 span',this).text("Down Arrow");
            }
        });
    });
```

**added CSS**

```
.arrow {
    float: right;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    margin-top: 21px;
    border-top-color: #F3F3F3;
}
.accordion-head.open .arrow {
    margin-top: 11px;
    border-bottom-color: #F3F3F3;
    border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/gu7h3/7/)

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/gu7h3/8/)

Comment: One problem tho, when you open a section and then click and open another one, the arrow in the previous one does not change back, it stay open.

Comment: You asked only to change the arrows anyhow I have fixed this now. check [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/gu7h3/8/)

Comment: @Nandhakumar This works for me up until I add a large body of text to the `<div class="accordion-body">`. When I do that, the accordion "boxes" spring open as expected, but the top of the "box" (where a reader may expect to begin reading) may be well off of the screen. How might we fix this so that the `accordion-body` div that is requested by the user is brought to the top of the focus area?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple JQuery solution to get this working. Im sure you can refine it, but at least it is going in the correct direction.

In the Head, H4 I have added a span with the "arrow text"

```
<h4>Section A<span>Down Arrow</span></h4>
```

..Changed the css for the span to float it right

```
.accordion .accordion-head span {
    float:right
}
```

and finally added a little JQuery to change the text

```
...   
if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
$(this).next().slideDown();
    $('h4 span',this).text("Up Arrow");
}else{
    $('h4 span',this).text("Down Arrow");
}
...
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gu7h3/6/)

Comment: One problem tho, when you open a section and then click and open another one, the arrow in the previous one does not change back, it stay open.