# How to Display Sorting Arrows in Column Header

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting, html-table

I know I'm a total newbie at this. So I am making a website for work. I got drafted since everyone else has even less knowledge. I created a huge table and got some help to create a basic script that allows me to sort my table.

Now I have a new issue. How do I get sorting arrows placed that change between up and down depending on the sorting of the list? I can place static arrows without any issue but I'm not sure about state dependent ones.

If there's an answer that only uses HTML/CSS that would be ideal but if I have to use JS I can manage.

Thanks a million!

Here's my current JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //grab all header rows
    $('th').each(function (column) {
        $(this).addClass('sortable').click(function () {
                var findSortKey = function ($cell) {
                    return $cell.find('.sort-key').text().toUpperCase()+ ' ' + $cell.text().toUpperCase();

                };
                var sortDirection = $(this).is('.sorted-asc') ? -1 : 1;
                var $rows = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('tbody tr').get();
                var bob = 0;
                //loop through all the rows and find
                $.each($rows, function (index, row) {
                    row.sortKey = findSortKey($(row).children('td').eq(column));
                });

                //compare and sort the rows alphabetically or numerically
                $rows.sort(function (a, b) {                       
                    if (a.sortKey.indexOf('-') == -1 && (!isNaN(a.sortKey) && !isNaN(a.sortKey))) {
                         //Rough Numeracy check                          

                            if (parseInt(a.sortKey) < parseInt(b.sortKey)) {
                                return -sortDirection;
                            }
                            if (parseInt(a.sortKey) > parseInt(b.sortKey)) {                                
                                return sortDirection;
                            }

                    } else {
                        if (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) {
                            return -sortDirection;
                        }
                        if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey) {
                            return sortDirection;
                        }
                    }
                    return 0;
                });

                //add the rows in the correct order to the bottom of the table
                $.each($rows, function (index, row) {
                    $('tbody').append(row);
                    row.sortKey = null;
                });

                //identify the column sort order
                $('th').removeClass('sorted-asc sorted-desc');
                var $sortHead = $('th').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')');
                sortDirection == 1 ? $sortHead.addClass('sorted-asc') : $sortHead.addClass('sorted-desc');

                //identify the column to be sorted by
                $('td').removeClass('sorted').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')').addClass('sorted');
            });
        });
    });
```

Some of the Table content:

```
    <table id="mtable">
                                      <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Measure</th>
                                            <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Acronym</th>
                                            <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Domain</th>
                                            <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Ages</th>
                                            <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Administration</th>
                                        </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="7u7d.html">7 Up/7 Down Inventory</a></td>
                                            <td>7U7D</td>
                                            <td>Mania</td>
                                            <td>Child</td>
                                            <td>Self</td>
                                        </tr>                                       
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="abc-c.html">Aberrant Behavior Checklist - Community</a></td>
                                            <td>ABC-C</td>
                                            <td>Autism</td>
                                            <td>All</td>
                                            <td>Informant/Clinician</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="aims.html">Abnormal Involuntary Movement Scale</a></td>
                                            <td>AIMS</td>                                   
                                            <td>Side Effects</td>
                                            <td>Unspecified</td>
                                            <td>Clinician</td>
                                        </tr>
```

Finally the CSS:

```
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

th  {
    font-weight: bold;
}

    table {
        width: 100%;
    }  
        table tbody tr {
            border-top: solid 1px #D2D7DC;
        }

            table tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
                background: #f9fbfe;
            }

        table td {
            padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
        }

        table th {
            text-align: left;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
        }

        table tfoot {
            border-top: solid 1px #D2D7DC;
        }
```

Comment: It's trivial in jQuery to toggle an image class, but here's some tutorials for how to do simple stuff like that without JS: https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-JavaScript

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Also, relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057720/toggle-up-and-down-arrows-in-a-simple-accordion-widget

Comment: How is the data being sorted in html table? Is it server side? or client side (with Javascript)? If it is server side you can decide which icon (up or down) to show based on what sorting the server just did. If it is client side then you will change source of image when triggering the sort.

Comment: I added the code. The table is an HTML table. I believe it's stored server side but I'm new at this so I might be wrong. Sorry if I sound dumb. Thanks for the other links. I'm looking into them!